# Proofs using article class

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

I am using the article class and using the amsthm package

Writing the code for the proofs of lemmas and then I get something like this:(Obviously the same happens for propositions etc.)

[image]

As you can see the proof of lemma 2 has a problem. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. (I've updated the code which looks more now to what I get in my project)

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace} 
 \doublespacing
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage {tikz}
\usepackage[skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage{authblk}


\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{apacite}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\bibliographystyle{apalike}



\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}


\definecolor {processblue}{cmyk}{0.96,0,0,0}
\newtheorem{As}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{Pro}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{col}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Exm}{Example}
 \newtheorem{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}


\begin{document}

\section{k}
\begin{lem}\label{lem1}
Lemma 1
\end{lem}

\begin{rem}\label{rem1}

Rem1
\end{rem}

\begin{lem}\label{lem2}
Lemma 2
\end{lem}
\section{j}
\appendix

\begin{proof}[Proof of Lemma \ref{lem1}]

Proofs

\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Proof of Rem
 \ref{rem1}]
 \begin{align*}
... \end{align*}
Proofs

\end{proof}


\begin{proof}{Proof of Lemma \ref{lem2}}
From assumption , we have... Hence we have ....., therefore ....... Moreover..... 


\end{proof}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, provide a MWE to see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Not at pc so cannot test, but does this compile without errors? I would assume theorems (here lem) needs to be defined in the preamble not in the document body.

Comment: In my computer your code throw errors. I put `\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}` in the preamble and comment the `\doublespacing` (Not sure but I believe you need `setspace` package for that command) and the code runs with no errors and with the desired output

Comment: Put square brackets around `Proof of Lemma \ref{lem2}` instead of braces. That's what you've done for the two other proofs.

Comment: Oops, how did I miss that! Thank you!

Comment: @KersouMan lol, never even saw that

Comment: Thanks for posting a great question! I’m going to vote to close it now because it was answered in the comments.

Comment: The typo causing the bug was solved in a comment.

Comment: Off topic: If loading both `amsmath` and `amsthm`, `amsmath` must be loaded first.  Also, there shouldn't be a blank line between the proof text and `\end{proof}`; a blank line will force the "tombstone" to be on a separate line, which isn't desirable.  (You might want to read the `amsthm` user's guide -- `texdoc amsthdoc`.)